# Single array in the hdf5 file

Tags: hdf5

Image of my dataset:
[image: Image of my dataset]

I am using the  HDF5DotNet with C# and I can read only full data as the attached image in the dataset. The hdf5 file is too big, up to nearly 10GB, and if I load the whole array into the memory then it will be out of memory.

I would like to read all data from rows 5 and 7 in the attached image. Is that anyway to read only these 2 rows data into memory in a time without having to load all data into memory first?

```c#
    private static void OpenH5File()
    {

        var h5FileId = H5F.open(@"D:\Sandbox\Flood Modeller\Document\xmdf_results\FMA_T1_10ft_001.xmdf", H5F.OpenMode.ACC_RDONLY);
        string dataSetName = "/FMA_T1_10ft_001/Temporal/Depth/Values";
        var dataset = H5D.open(h5FileId, dataSetName);
        var space = H5D.getSpace(dataset);
        var dataType = H5D.getType(dataset);

        long[] offset = new long[2];
        long[] count = new long[2];
        long[] stride = new long[2];
        long[] block = new long[2];

        offset[0] = 1;     // start at row 5
        offset[1] = 2;     // start at column 0

        count[0] = 2;      // read 2 rows
        count[0] = 165701; // read all columns

        stride[0] = 0;     // don't skip anything
        stride[1] = 0;

        block[0] = 1;      // blocks are single elements
        block[1] = 1;

        // Dataspace associated with the dataset in the file
        // Select a hyperslab from the file dataspace
        H5S.selectHyperslab(space, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, offset, count, block);
        // Dimensions of the file dataspace
        var dims = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(space);

        // We also need a memory dataspace which is the same size as the file dataspace
        var memspace = H5S.create_simple(2, dims);

        double[,] dataArray = new double[1, dims[1]]; // just get one array
        var wrapArray = new H5Array<double>(dataArray);

        // Now we can read the hyperslab
        H5D.read(dataset, dataType, memspace, space,
                 new H5PropertyListId(H5P.Template.DEFAULT), wrapArray);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to select a hyperslab which has the correct *offset*, *count*, *stride*, and *block* for the subset of the dataset that you wish to read. These are all arrays which have the same number of dimensions as your dataset.
The *block* is the size of the element block in each dimension to read, i.e. 1 is a single element.
The *offset* is the number of *blocks* from the start of the dataset to start reading, and *count* is the number of *blocks* to read.
You can select non-contiguous regions by using *stride*, which again counts in *blocks*.

I'm afraid I don't know C#, so the following is in C. In your example, you would have:

```
hsize_t offset[2], count[2], stride[2], block[2];

offset[0] = 5;     // start at row 5
offset[1] = 0;     // start at column 0

count[0] = 2;      // read 2 rows
count[1] = 165702; // read all columns

stride[0] = 1;     // don't skip anything
stride[1] = 1;

block[0] = 1;      // blocks are single elements
block[1] = 1;

// This assumes you already have an open dataspace with ID dataspace_id
H5Sselect_hyperslab(dataspace_id, H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, stride, count, block)
```

You can find more information on reading/writing hyperslabs in the [HDF5 tutorial](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/selectsimple.html).

---

It seems there are two forms of `H5D.read` in C#, you want the [second form](http://hdf5.net/api/M_HDF5DotNet_H5D_read%60%601_6_cdcc6ef4.aspx):

```cs
H5D.read(Type) Method (H5DataSetId, H5DataTypeId, H5DataSpaceId,
                       H5DataSpaceId, H5PropertyListId, H5Array(Type))
```

This allows you specify the memory and file dataspaces. Essentially, you need one dataspace which has information about the size, stride, offset, etc. of the variable in memory that you want to read *into*; and one dataspace for the dataset in the file that you want to read *from*. This lets you do things like read from a non-contiguous region in a file to a contiguous region in an array in memory.

You want something like

```cs
// Dataspace associated with the dataset in the file
var dataspace = H5D.get_space(dataset);
// Select a hyperslab from the file dataspace
H5S.selectHyperslab(dataspace, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, offset, count);
// Dimensions of the file dataspace
var dims = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(dataspace);
// We also need a memory dataspace which is the same size as the file dataspace
var memspace = H5S.create_simple(rank, dims);

// Now we can read the hyperslab
H5D.read(dataset, datatype, memspace, dataspace, 
         new H5PropertyListId(H5P.Template.DEFAULT), wrapArray);
```

---

From your posted code, I think I've spotted the problem. First you do this:

```cs
 var space = H5D.getSpace(dataset);
```

then you do

```cs
 var dataspace = H5D.getSpace(dataset);
```

These two calls do the same thing, but create two different variables
You call `H5S.selectHyperslab` with `space`, but `H5D.read` uses `dataspace`.
You need to make sure you are using the correct variables consistently. If you remove the second call to `H5D.getSpace`, and change `dataspace -> space`, it should work.

Comment: Thak you. I can use it in C# but I cannot get the data correctly just for that row only. Can you please write the additional code how to retrieve the data of that block to array ?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include what you are already doing?

Comment: H5S.selectHyperslab(space, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, offset, count);
var dims = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(space);
double[,] dataArray = new double[1, dims[1]]; // just get one array
var wrapArray = new H5Array<double>(dataArray);
H5D.read(dataset, dataType, wrapArray); // it seems that I cannot use stride and block in C# command

Comment: I get this error after all An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in HDF5DotNet.dll

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

Comment: Please can you add your code to your original question? It's not properly formatted in the comments, which makes it difficult to read.

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->
H5S.selectHyperslab(space, H5S.SelectOperator.SET, offset, count);
var dims = H5S.getSimpleExtentDims(space);
double[,] dataArray = new double[1, dims[1]]; // just get one array
var wrapArray = new H5Array<double>(dataArray);
H5D.read(dataset, dataType, wrapArray);

Comment: I cannot format well at all. I am not sure how we can do it with this. Shall the above code ok ?

Comment: Many thanks for this. I still cannot get it right indeed. I check the code that after using the selectHyperslab and then I get the dimension for the space allocated still array [37, 165702] - the total values in the dataset. It just cannot get the data for just 1 or 2 rows only. What I would expect to get is that after calling the selectHyperslab with the right parameter it shall give me the return of [2, 165702] array. But anyway it does not work.

Comment: Basically I make the same offset and count value as in your example. The array dimension seems to be right. It's the 2d array of double.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on. Please can you edit your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I give the same offset value as in your example as below


hsize_t offset[2], count[2], stride[2], block[2];

offset[0] = 5;     // start at row 5
offset[1] = 0;     // start at column 0

count[0] = 2;      // read 2 rows
count[1] = 165702; // read all columns

stride[0] = 1;     // don't skip anything
stride[1] = 1;

block[0] = 1;      // blocks are single elements
block[1] = 1;

Comment: Sorry, but it's really very unreadable if you post code in a comment. If you scroll up, there's an "edit" button under your original question. Please use that to edit your question and add the code there. You can see how I did it before. Also, please read the link I posted above about minimal complete examples. It would be very useful to see what you're doing, from start to finish.

Comment: Thank you and I already edited the original question now. Many thanks for this

Comment: I edited the original codes as your suggestions and it just does not work . I am not sure what else is wrong indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to have a look at [HDFql](http://www.hdfql.com) as it abstracts yourself from the low-level details of HDF5. Using HDFql in C#, you can read rows #5 and #7 of dataset `Values` using a hyperslab selection like this:

```cs
float [,]data = new float[2, 165702];

HDFql.Execute("SELECT FROM Values[5:2:2:1] INTO MEMORY " + HDFql.VariableTransientRegister(data));
```

Afterwards, you can access these rows through variable `data`. Example:

```cs
for(int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < 165702; y++)
    {
         System.Console.WriteLine(data[x, y]);
    }
}
```